# How can I force UI refresh in nativescript-core?

Tags: nativescript

I have a nativescript-core View which is not displaying properly.  If I update my css, the view refreshes and everything is great.  How can I do this programatically?

The functions which I have tried so far are all listed here: https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#initnativeview

They have been

```
view.initNativeView();
view.requestLayout();
view.resetNativeView();
view._updateStyleScope();
```

none of these have updated the view

Comment: Technically `requestLayout()` should have worked for force relayout. Can you share a Playground sample where your issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not.  Whatever the bug is, it seems to be very specific to iOS, on one particular page which (seemingly) has nothing in particular different about it.  If requestLayout() is supposed to work, I'm glad to know that.  So far, the only thing that has worked is removing the className, waiting .5s, then resetting it.

Comment: I am having trouble with a plugin. The only solution I have found so far is to remove, create new instance and add. Those functions neither did work for me.

Answer (score -3):

put your code inside

`function onNavigatingTo(args) {
   //your code here
}
exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;`

that way each time you go to the page it reloads/refresh

Comment: I'm not using the page component.